# Compare two list of lists and only keep matching elements while maintaining the structure

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

Given the following two nested lists:

```
alist = [[1,4,10,2], [4,1,12,10], [5,12,4,10], [5,10,2,4]]

blist = [[2,4,10,9,13,20], [12,9,20,33,Not,15], [3,1,2,7,4,8], [Not,9,8,3,4,5]]
```

I am trying to compare both list by list while maintaining the list structure and only keep the matches like so:

```
newlist= [[4,10,2], [12], [4], [5,4]]
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: mean `newlist= [[4,10,2]...`?

Comment: Why is second element of newlist []?

Comment: Thanks - these were my mistakes. You are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `set.intersection()` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection)):

```
Not = object()

alist = [[1,4,10,2], [4,1,12,10], [5,12,4,10], [5,10,2,4]]

blist = [[2,4,10,9,13,20], [12,9,20,33,Not,15], [3,1,2,7,4,8], [Not,9,8,3,4,5]]

new_list = [list(set(i).intersection(j)) for i, j in zip(alist, blist)]
print(new_list)
```

Prints:

```
[[2, 10, 4], [12], [4], [4, 5]]
```

Comment: First of all - thanks for the response!
But this seems only to be working partly without `list`-argument after the first bracket.

When I did `new_list = [(set(i).intersection(j)) for i, j in zip(alist, blist)]`

I got: `[{2, 10, 4}, {12}, {4}, {4, 5}]`